# Partial match LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

In my query

```
    public IEnumerable<RepInfo> GetRepsByCountry(string country)
    {
    var reps = RepInfoProvider.GetReps()
        .WhereLike("CountriesCovered", $"%{country}%")
        .ToList();
 return reps;
    }
```

Countries Covered in the database is a semicolon separated list (Example: Germany; Norway; Spain; Romainia)

When the country passed in is Oman, the list returned contains data related to Romania (because OMAN is in Romania), is there a way to use wherelike but filter out if it's not an exact match?

Comment: Any chance to change this incorrect database schema?

Comment: Are there spaces between the semicolons and the country-names or not - and is there a semicolon at the start and end of the string? (e.g. (`Germany; Norway` vs `Germany;Norway` vs `;Germany; Norway;` )?

Comment: It was setup before I took it over, it will never start with a ; but will always end with one and there will be a space

Example: Germany; Spain; Romania;

Comment: Please show us the definition of `WhereLike` - that isn't a standard Linq-to-Entities operator AFAIK. Why aren't you using the `Expression<>`-based Linq methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a in-memory search afterwards. Only recommended with a few rows

```
var reps = RepInfoProvider.GetReps()
        .WhereLike("CountriesCovered", $"%{country}%")
        .ToList()
        .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.CountriesCovered, $"\\b{country}\\b"))
        .ToList()
```

Comment: changed to Regex

Answer (score 0):

**Better idea**: Normalize your database design so you can directly query that country-list without needing to do string processing in SQL, which is horrible.

---

Anyway,

If all of the substrings in `CountriesCovered` are semicolon-separated then and if you want to an exact match then you need to put the semicolons in your search string *inside* the `%` wildcards.

I assume there is a space after the semicolon, before the country name.

I also assume the `CountriesCovered` string doesn't have a semicolon at the start and end of the entire string - which means you need to test for those cases with an `OR`...

In SQL this would be this (using literals, not parameters for clarity):

```sql
WHERE
    ( CountriesCovered LIKE '%; Oman;%' )    -- Word is inside string.
    OR
    ( CountriesCovered LIKE 'Oman;%' )       -- Word is at start of string.
    OR
    ( CountriesCovered LIKE '%; Oman' )      -- Word is at end of string.
```

In Linq-to-Entities, this would be something like this:

```cs
List<Rep> reps = await dbContext.Reps
    .Where( r =>
        r.CountriesCovered.Contains( "; Oman;" )
        ||
        r.CountriesCovered.StartsWith( "Oman;" )
        ||
        r.CountriesCovered.EndsWith( "; Oman" )
    )
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

EF will convert the `String.Contains`, `StartsWith`, and `EndsWith` function expressions to T-SQL `LIKE` operators with the `%` wildcards added automatically.